# Numerical minimization of an objective function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Here is my problem: I've got an objective function f[..] to minimize (numerically with the help of FindMinimum[...] procedure) that depends on a variable number of arguments, i.e. one time it will be minimized when depending on 5 variables, next time on 10, and another on 20 or even more. Instead of creating separate function definitions for each of these cases, I would like to define my objective function once like f[X_], where inside the body of the function I could refer to the optimizable arguments in this way: X[1],X[2],X[3],...,X[n]. The body of the function involves numerical solution to a differential equation with the help of NDSolveValue[..] procedure, so I also want to define my objective function that is only intended to evaluate for numerical values of the variables like this: f[X_?NumberQ] := Cos[X[1]^2 - 3 X[2]] + Sin[X[2]^2 + X[1]^2]. Unfortunately, this approach does not work and I cannot manage to get it right.
Please, provide some help. Looking forward to your feedback and suggestions.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `f[X_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Cos[X[[1]]^2 - 3 X[[2]]] + Sin[X[[2]]^2 + X[[1]]^2]; f[{1., 2.}]`

Comment: Thank you very much, Bob. Your definition works just fine, but I still have an issue with minimizing this function. Here's what I tried and got as a response from the system: FindMinimum[f[x], {x[[1]], 5.0}, {x[[2]], 6.0}] -> FindMinimum::vloc: The variable x[[1]] cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values. Any thought on how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Cos[x[[1]]^2 - 3 x[[2]]] + Sin[x[[2]]^2 + x[[1]]^2];

NMinimize[{f[x], x ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]}, x]

(* {-2., {x -> {-5.32352, -6.26134}}} *)

NMinimize[{f[x], x ∈ Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]}, x]

(* {-2., {x -> {-1.37638, 1.67868}}} *)

NMinimize[{f[x], x ∈ Vectors[2, PositiveReals]}, x]

(* {-2., {x -> {2.12265, 0.454686}}} *)

NMinimize[{f[x], x ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}, x]

(* {-2., {x -> {1.37638, 1.67868}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Works like a charm.